# xpages default value for computed field

Tags: xpages

The computedField is binded to a datasource field:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{Contr.txt_nrcontractcv}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
```

But, I want to have a default value, something like this:

```
NumberValue := @Subset(@DbColumn ("NOTES":"NOCACHE";"";"vwNrRegistru";1); -1);
@If(@Elements(NumberValue) < 1;10001;NumberValue + 1)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed field is a display-only component. It does not set any value back to the data binding. That's why it does not have a default value. Instead, you might set the value as SSJS:

```
if(Contr.hasItem("txt_nrcontractcv")) {
  return Contr.getItemValueInteger("txt_nrcontractcv");
} else {
  return yourDefaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Serdar is correct, Computed Field should not be thought of like a field of type computed in traditional Notes. Think of it as computed text.

If you want to make a value non-editable but want to change the value in the back-end document, there are two options.

1. Still use the Computed Field control but update the document independently.
2. Use an Input Text control, set the default value and set disabled="true".